# Converting JSON to C# class deserializer errors on List

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization, jsonserializer

I have this JSON object - in view mode

```
[{
    "Urltitle": "",
    "location": "",
    "Url": ""
}, {
    "Urltitle": "",
    "location": "",
    "Url": ""
}, {
    "Urltitle": "",
    "location": "",
    "Url": ""
}]
```

Class:

```
namespace Models
{
    public partial class Urls
    {
        public string Urltitle { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Use this deserializer:

```
IList<T> ssdResponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IList<T>>(content, JsonOptions);
```

But Keep getting error:

> 'The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Models.Urls]. Path: $[0] | LineNumber: 0 |

I've tried solutions online but cannot get this successfully mapped - am I missing something?

Comment: The name in your error message is different from the name of the class you included

Comment: `Path: $[0] | LineNumber: 0` - are you sure that’s the JSON you’re actually trying to deserialise? Seeing an error in the very first character suggests it’s something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a quick .NET Fiddle for your scenario. The deserialization works fine for the example you provided.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/4C6HEw

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s = """"
            [{
                "Urltitle": "",
                "location": "",
                "Url": ""
            }, {
                "Urltitle": "",
                "location": "",
                "Url": ""
            }, {
                "Urltitle": "",
                "location": "",
                "Url": ""
            }]
            """";
        var list = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Urls>>(s);
        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(list));
    }

    public partial class Urls
    {
        public string Urltitle { get; set; }

        public string location { get; set; }

        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You'd need to check if your actual JSON (or class) has a slightly different structure etc. that would cause issue with deserialization.